# Spinnaker halyard deployment - overriding readinessprobe configuration

Tags: spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

How to override readinessprobe configuration in halyard config for Spinnaker deployment through Halyard?

Front50 is taking time (~60 secs ) to start and hence healthcheckfails as the default timeout is set to 1 sec.

Default readinessprobe config for Front50 deployment through halyard:

```
readinessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      periodSeconds: 10
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help:

```
hal config deploy edit --liveness-probe-enabled true --liveness-probe-initial-delay-seconds $LONGEST_SERVICE_STARTUP_TIME

hal deploy apply
```

The hal config options seem to have only liveness probe delay argument.

Ref:
https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/install/environment/#distributed-installation